# Next.Js 13 using app. page.css is affecting page.js where it's not linked

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am new to Next.JS and come across many problems, and usually am able to figure it out, but I just can't fix this one.
I need to change some body properties so in the (response)/success I have imported the page.css only on page.js in the same directory. No other page.js or layout.js has page.css imported.
When the first root page loads everything is fine, but when I go to the /success and come back to the root page the body changes from /success (page.css) also stay in the root page.

I first noticed it when I have pushed the changes and on the vercel, the root page had the page.css changes right away, but not on the localhost.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.